# MacOS vs. Windows MyFonts.com Font Rendering Line Height

Tags: css, fonts, font-face

We have a problem with line heights on MacOS El Capitan in comparison to Windows. This happens with a lot of fonts we purchased on myfonts.com. Currently we use the font "Optima". We use simple buttons with the css code:

```
#button {
    border-radius:20px;
    padding:10px 50px;
    background-color:grey;
    color:#fff;
    font-size:24px;
    display:inline-block;
    text-decoration:none;   
}
```

I have attached a screenshot. Clearly on the mac os version the font is 1px too near at the top.

[image]

I have tried all possible combinations on the myfonts export kit page but nothing changes this behaviour.

Do you have any suggestion how we can fix this issue?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? We're having the same problem.

Comment: Nope. Also the myfonts.com Support doesn't provide any useful answers.